# Tag rename request: file-manger

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retagging

Unless we're talking about baby files lying newborn in a manger, could we rename the [file-manger](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-manger) tag to [file-manager](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-manager)?

:)

Comment: But what about all those baby files?? I am really concerned about them! No mangers, what next? No diapers??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, a no-brainer :-) Good catch! It's renamed now.

Here's a discussion about [how to rename a tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87437/how-to-rename-a-tag) on Stack Exchange's Meta site. It requires a moderator to do, so you did the right thing by opening up a Meta discussion about it.

Comment: That was fast! Yeah I was pretty sure if I didn't have rep for a synonym I wouldn't be able to rename either ;) Thx for the link though!

Comment: No problem, the link was just in case anyone else (including moderators) goes looking for a "tag renaming" option since there isn't an obvious one.